# Installing Ubuntu and problem with boot loader (Trying with Try Ubuntu 14.04 version)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

[Currently there is no operating system installed in the PC]
I have been trying to install ubuntu 14.04 in my PC. The problem I'm having is that problem in installing  grub in software. 
[image]
[[image]

What I think the problem is in my hard-disk  file system.  I tried to wipe it out using G-Parted but, some of the file named  "RIOD" wasn't go disappear. I have tried to  fix the boot loader problem but each time it's showing the same problem. Do you have any idea how I can reformat  the hard rive and  install a ubuntu? I don't care about previous memory of my hard drive.

[image]

[image]jpg

Answer (score 0):

There is a direct command `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` to show grub menu on boot, but to execute, you need access to Windows OS.

The steps are:

- Boot into `Windows` OS
- Combine `Windows` + `r` together and type `cmd` to open command prompt.
- Type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and hit `Enter`

P.S : To get dual boot working fine on my dell laptop, I took help of this link [dual boot windows and ubuntu](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) and I followed above steps too for setting up the grub menu and it worked.

I would advice you to crosscheck your process with the above mentioned link. It will help you understand if you are missing something during the installation process just in case.

Comment: So what you are saying is that, formatting hard disk using windows  operating system, and  then install the ubuntu?

Comment: First check the link to see if you have performed every step given there. If you are sure that you installed Ubuntu properly, then 
1) Boot into Windows. 2) Press `Ctrl` + `r` keys and type `cmd`] . 3) Once you are in command prompt window, just type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and hit `Enter` key. 

The command will execute. Once done, restart your system and you will be presented with Grub menu (if Ubuntu got installed successfully in the first step).


We will format the Ubuntu partition using `Windows OS` if we have to reinstall Ubuntu all over again.

Comment: The problem is that, I couldn't install  the ubuntu successfully. That was the  "try ubuntu" version

Comment: then in that case brother, you need to first install Ubuntu on a separate partition. Once you have installed it, then you can follow the steps for setting up grub menu. 

Just follow the link I gave and the steps I mentioned, all will be fine. Still if you encounter any issues, let us know.

Comment: But the hard drive is not  taking  the ubuntu installation. The first picture  is added here where the installation  failed each time.

Comment: Take a complete backup of your Windows OS data on a separate portable hard disk.

Boot into `Gparted` and wipe out your hard disk completely deleting all Windows and other partitions. Reinstall Windows afresh using bootable USB recreating all partitions. 
. 

Once done, then initiate Ubuntu installation using a bootable USB.

Use `Universal USB Installer` software for creating bootable USB in both the cases.